# Find variance of Asset with lesser return to make a pure portfolio of it the min-variance portfolio

Tags: portfolio-optimization, mean-variance

I need to solve the question mentioned above. For an asset with a worse payoff than another, I need to determine a variance for which the minimum-variance portfolio only consists of this asset.
There are only two assets and a short-selling constraint.

My first guess would be that this asset would need to be risk-free for it to be preferable to the other one and lie on the efficient-frontier, but maybe there is a mathematical way to solve this I can't find in my script/books?

Comment: Hint 1) the MVP does not consider the assets expected return. Hint 2) What is the formula for the MVP in the two-asset-case?

Comment: Why not assuming perfect positive correlation? Then the asset with the worst return and lower variance is the MVP..

Comment: Hint 3) the conditions for a 2-asset MVP to have no short sales is given here https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/24497/under-which-conditions-the-minimum-variance-portfolio-involves-no-short-selling